# Nested loops to add data to a Google Sheet

Tags: python

For a school football project, I used this code to generate a fixture.

```
teams = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for hometeam in teams:
   for awayteam in teams:
      if hometeam != awayteam:
         print (hometeam + ' vs ' + awayteam)
```

Now I would like to do two things.

1. As it stands, it is generating all possible matches between the teams. But I would like for the team to go against each other only once.
2. I would like to add the fixtures to the Google Sheet automatically, e.g. hometeam will be listed under hometeam column as for awayteam.

Answer (score 1):

The function `enumerate()` will return both the index and value of each list element: `(1,'a'), (2,'b')` etc.
Then you just can pair elements where the first index is lower than the second:

```
teams = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for i, hometeam in enumerate(teams):
   for j, awayteam in enumerate(teams):
      if j > i:
         print (hometeam + ' vs ' + awayteam)
```

Comment: Wow thanks, by any chance do you know how I can enter what is being printed on google sheet?

Comment: not really, sorry, but you could try copy and paste